# SQL ORACLE Combining two table with htf (hypertext functions)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm working on SQL ORACLE DATABASE and I create a table than going into foor loob and working with htf for convert table to html formate.

```
create table first_table (id number, data varchar2(25));
insert into first_table values(101, 'numberone')
insert into first_table values(202, 'numbertwo')

create table second_table (no number, data varchar2(25));
insert into second_table values(05369277635, 'phoneone')
insert into second_table values(06362190876, 'phonetwo')

DECLARE
  v_html VARCHAR2(32767);
  s_html VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEOPEN('border="1px"');
  v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
  v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEHEADER('ID.DATA');
  v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
  s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEOPEN('border="1px"');
  s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
  s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEHEADER('NUMBER.DATA');
  s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM first_table) LOOP
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEDATA(i.id||'.'||i.data);
    v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
END LOOP;
FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM second_table) LOOP
    s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
    s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEDATA(i.no||'.'||i.data);
    s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
END LOOP;
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLECLOSE;
s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLECLOsE;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_html);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(s_html);
```

end;

I use this code and result like that;

```
ID.DATA
101.numberone
202.numbertwo
NUMBER.DATA
5369277635.phoneone
6362190876.phonetwo
```

However I want to see like;

```
ID.DATA
101.numberone
NUMBER.DATA
5369277635.phoneone
ID.DATA
202.numbertwo
NUMBER.DATA
6362190876.phonetwo
```

Is it possible that column by column separate?

Answer (score 0):

Are those tables really unrelated? I *suppose* that - in real life - there should be relation between them. If so, you'd use nested FOR loops, such as this:

```
   FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM first_table)
   LOOP
      v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
      v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEDATA (i.ID || '.' || i.DATA);
      v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;

      FOR j IN (SELECT *
                  FROM second_table s
                 WHERE s.ID = i.ID --> you'd add such a condition, to join those tables
               )
      LOOP
         s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
         s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEDATA (j.NO || '.' || j.DATA);
         s_html := s_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
```

Comment: Actually in my project they aren't but I gave a simple example for less code because mine was really so much. I understood your answer. Thank you so much.